# Spring Request Scope replacement on fail

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

I have a problem with spring request scope. It works fine in 99.9% of my calls, because there is almost always a web request available. Unfortunately a few things are done via `@Async` and here things get tricky.

My desired solution is to replace the bean using **`@Scope(value = "request" proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`** with basically the same implementation but using a prototype scope.
I could have both beans inheriting from the same parent and then add the different scopes.

However I have no idea how to make this work. As we have the same Bean, I will get an error that the bean is not unique.
The logic would be to try to create the primary request scope bean and on failure catch the `BeanCreationException` and replace it with the prototype implementation.

I cannot find a solution with `@Primary` or named beans here, because in principle, the context of the calling method (somewhere higher in the callstack, i.e. Async or not) decides, whether the bean will be of type request or prototype.

Unfortunately I have not found any real solution for this so far.

Comment: Abondon that idea. You cannot use a prototype scoped bean as scoped proxy as each method call would be invoked on a new instance. So it will simply not work. Instead fix the actual problem and that is using request scoped beans in background threads. Which means pass the needed data into the async method instead of relying on a request scoped bean.

Comment: I was already afraid, that it might not work, however passing all the data to the bean is not feasible as the reason for the request scope is rather the time to live instead of actual request data (in this instance some data is cached to reduce external calls, just for the lifetime of a single request--for the async cases, I could live without the cache)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be feasible? Create a new instance of the bean yourself, copy the data from the request scoped bean and pass it as a method argument to the async method. Problem solved.

Comment: It is an autowired bean, that is not used by the async method directly. It is somewhere deep in the callstack and the calling methods are used syncronously and asyncronously.

Comment: My last comment brought me to an idea: Might this work? Instead of autowiring I will get the application context and get the bean in the constructor. If the exception occurs I will then instantiate the other bean. It would be a workaround because I need to get all the instances where the bean might be called asyncronously, which at least in my current example is at least not much (more like 2 occurrences).

Comment: Without seeing and knowing what you are doing that is impossible to answer.